# How do I enable the preview panel for TypeScript files in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I miss the feature that would show you the results of your TypeScript compile in a separate panel. I haven't found a way to turn that back on in Visual Studio 2015 with TypeScript 1.5 beta.

I have WebEssentials for 2015 installed as well as ReSharper 9.1.

Anyone have any luck with this?

Comment: I posted the same question to the WebEssentials Q&A pane. Hopefully we will get a response.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This has been removed from Web Essentials 2015 in VS 2015RC.

See: https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2015/issues/53

> madskristensen commented on Jun 8
>
> The TS preview pane has been removed from Web Essentials 2015 due to continuously running into conflicts with the TS compiler when new versions come out. The TS team are aware of it and I hope they will add the feature into the TS tooling in the future. It is possible that this feature will be included in the brand new Web Compiler extensions (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b329021-cd7a-4a01-86fc-714c2d05bb6c) when preview panes have been implemented.

Comment: I submitted a request to Microsoft but unfortunately they have no intention to bring this feature back. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2264309/typescript-preview-window-not-working-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: Oddly, the Web Essentials website still lists this as a VS 2015 feature: http://vswebessentials.com/features/typescript#preview

Comment: Isn't this like Deja-vu all over again?

Comment: So sad. Why did he remove it instead of adding an option to disable the pane? It was a killer feature and i had no issues with it.

Answer (score 42):

Alternatively, you can hit the "Show All Files" Button in the Solution Explorer to find your `.js` file and then hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd> to get a vertical split window and open the `.js` file right next to your `.ts` file.

Comment: I think this must be the accepted solution.This works.Thanks :)

Comment: Looks like this has changed a bit. I don't seem to find "Show All Files" button in the solution explorer. But I can hit "File" -> open the js file and split it next to my .ts file. This works as well.

Answer (score 2):

This issue still exists as of 2015-07-30 using the officially released version of Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition plus Web Essentials 2015 version 0.5.1.

None of the previous suggestions work.

Mads needs to fix this and release a new version.

P.S. This issue does not happen with VS 2013 Update 4 and the latest Web Essentials 2013.