# How to enable javascript preview in VS 15

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

In VS13, Web Essentials included a feature to preview the generated JavaScript in the same window as the Typescript.

I cannot find this feature in VS15 RC that I just downloaded and installed.

According to Mads Kristensen:  [The TypeScript tooling contains all those options now. You don't need Web Essentials for any of that anymore.](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee6e6d8c-c837-41fb-886a-6b50ae2d06a2/view/Reviews/2)

But I can't find where to enable that feature.

Comment: see also the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019323/how-do-i-enable-the-preview-panel-for-typescript-files-in-visual-studio-2015)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `compileOnSave` is available, just open the generated `.js` file in a split pain view and you are off to the races.